# Addig SSL certificate / Cloud Front distribution to website does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

The website is hosted in aws bucket, public access enabled, and it worked with http
Trying to add https access - requested / added certificate, configured Cloud Front distribution, read a bunch of suggestions on StackOverflow, still not working.

When origin is configured as mywebsite.com.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com as prompted by CloudFront dropdown, I get XMl (not HTML) error NoSuchKey for index.html (which is there).

When I use website endpoint
mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

[www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) is redirected to mywebsite.com

Everything is AWS-based, read everything I can find, updated bucket policies, etc.
Nothing seems to help.  Any ideas where I can look for a solution?

{
"ETag": "E2UARY2PF3JN6L",
"Distribution": {
"Id": "E2VAMJ3R5UEYSD",
"ARN": "arn:aws:cloudfront::098706368979:distribution/E2VAMJ3R5UEYSD",
"Status": "Deployed",
"LastModifiedTime": "2021-08-18T19:41:28.165Z",
"InProgressInvalidationBatches": 0,
"DomainName": "dwm6otdm3onq4.cloudfront.net",
"ActiveTrustedSigners": {
"Enabled": false,
"Quantity": 0
},
"DistributionConfig": {
"CallerReference": "49a807de-37a4-4c9f-add6-739dcffd27cb",
"Aliases": {
"Quantity": 2,
"Items": [
"www.mywebsite.com",
"mywebsite.com"
]
},
"DefaultRootObject": "index.html",
"Origins": {
"Quantity": 2,
"Items": [
{
"Id": "www.mywebsite.com.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
"DomainName": "mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
"OriginPath": "",
"CustomHeaders": {
"Quantity": 0
},
"CustomOriginConfig": {
"HTTPPort": 80,
"HTTPSPort": 443,
"OriginProtocolPolicy": "match-viewer",
"OriginSslProtocols": {
"Quantity": 3,
"Items": [
"TLSv1",
"TLSv1.1",
"TLSv1.2"
]
},
"OriginReadTimeout": 30,
"OriginKeepaliveTimeout": 5
}
},
{
"Id": "mywebsite.com.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
"DomainName": "mywebsite.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
"OriginPath": "",
"CustomHeaders": {
"Quantity": 0
},
"CustomOriginConfig": {
"HTTPPort": 80,
"HTTPSPort": 443,
"OriginProtocolPolicy": "http-only",
"OriginSslProtocols": {
"Quantity": 3,
"Items": [
"TLSv1",
"TLSv1.1",
"TLSv1.2"
]
},
"OriginReadTimeout": 30,
"OriginKeepaliveTimeout": 5
}
}
]
},
"OriginGroups": {
"Quantity": 0
},
"DefaultCacheBehavior": {
"TargetOriginId": "www.mywebsite.com.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
"ForwardedValues": {
"QueryString": false,
"Cookies": {
"Forward": "none"
},
"Headers": {
"Quantity": 0
},
"QueryStringCacheKeys": {
"Quantity": 0
}
},
"TrustedSigners": {
"Enabled": false,
"Quantity": 0
},
"ViewerProtocolPolicy": "redirect-to-https",
"MinTTL": 0,
"AllowedMethods": {
"Quantity": 2,
"Items": [
"HEAD",
"GET"
],
"CachedMethods": {
"Quantity": 2,
"Items": [
"HEAD",
"GET"
]
}
},
"SmoothStreaming": false,
"DefaultTTL": 0,
"MaxTTL": 0,
"Compress": true,
"LambdaFunctionAssociations": {
"Quantity": 0
},
"FieldLevelEncryptionId": ""
},
"CacheBehaviors": {
"Quantity": 0
},
"CustomErrorResponses": {
"Quantity": 0
},
"Comment": "",
"Logging": {
"Enabled": false,
"IncludeCookies": false,
"Bucket": "",
"Prefix": ""
},
"PriceClass": "PriceClass_100",
"Enabled": true,
"ViewerCertificate": {
"ACMCertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:098706368979:certificate/8213cadd-5efd-44ad-b252-3d2cb7bed408",
"SSLSupportMethod": "sni-only",
"MinimumProtocolVersion": "TLSv1.2_2021",
"Certificate": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:098706368979:certificate/8213cadd-5efd-44ad-b252-3d2cb7bed408",
"CertificateSource": "acm"
},
"Restrictions": {
"GeoRestriction": {
"RestrictionType": "none",
"Quantity": 0
}
},
"WebACLId": "",
"HttpVersion": "http2",
"IsIPV6Enabled": true
},
"AliasICPRecordals": [
{
"CNAME": "www.mywebsite.com",
"ICPRecordalStatus": "APPROVED"
},
{
"CNAME": "mywebsite.com",
"ICPRecordalStatus": "APPROVED"
}
]
}
}

aws s3api get-bucket-policy --bucket mywebsite.com
{

```
    "Policy": "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"PublicReadGetObject\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:GetObject\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.com/*\"},{\"Sid\":\"PublicReadGetObjectVersion\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:GetObjectVersion\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.com/*\"},{\"Sid\":\"PublicListBucket\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":\"*\",\"Action\":\"s3:ListBucket\",\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:s3:::mywebsite.com\"}]}"
}
```

➜  ~ aws s3api get-bucket-website --bucket mywebsite.com

```
{ 
    "IndexDocument": {
        "Suffix": "index.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to provide exact details of your CF and bucket setup.

Comment: @Marcin, thank you for offering to help, the CLI output is too big for a comment, can you please ping me at flareplf@yahoo.com?  Thank you!

Comment: @Marcin, added CLI information to the original post. TIA for your help!